# In Bash, How would you only read lines in a log past a certain timestamp?

Tags: string, parsing, awk, grep, timestamp

So right now I'm trying to do the following:

```
grep "string" logfile.txt
```

which is going fine, but there's a lot of "string" in logfile.txt; I really only want to see the last hour's worth. In pseudo-code I want to do...

```
grep "string" logfile.txt  OnlyShowThoseInTheLastHour
```

Is there any way to easily accomplish this in bash? In the logfile the lines look like this:

```
13:27:50  string   morestuff morestuff morestuff
```

edit: sorry I forgot to mention it, but seeing logs from similar hours on past days is not an issue as these logs are refreshed/archived daily.

Comment: Is there no date in the timestamp?  How do you distinguish entries from 24+ hours ago?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention! This is not an issue as the logs archive and start fresh every midnight.

Comment: If you have the timestamp, for example `13:04:42`, after which all logs should be taken, `awk -v ts=13:04:42 '$1 > ts' < INPUTFILE`

Comment: Would not be easier, if you just displayed certain number of lines from end from grep? `grep "string" logfile.txt | tail -n 200`

Comment: @once unfrotunately I need this timing to be somewhat precise, if there were only 150 outputs in the last hour and I rain a tail -n 200, it would fire off some processes that should remain dormant.

JoSo I'm going to start trying to work that into a way to make it "most recent hour" that might just be the answer i need

Comment: You can solve this with [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN { tm = strftime("%H:%M:%S", systime()-3600) } /string/ && $1 >= tm' logfile.txt
```

Replace `string` by the pattern you're interested in.

It works by first building a string holding time information from 1 hour ago in `HH:MM:SS` format, and then selecting those lines that only match `string` and have the first field (timestamp) lexicographically greater than or equal to the timestamp string just built.

Note that it has its limitations, for example, if you do this at 00:30, log entries from 23:30 through 23:59 will not match. In general, running this command anytime between 00:00 and 00:59 will possibly omit log entries from 23:00 through 23:59. However, this shouldn't be an issue for you, since you mentioned (in the comments) that logs archive and start fresh every midnight.

Also, leap seconds are not dealt with, but this is probably not a problem unless you need 100% precise results. And again - since logs start afresh at midnight, in your specific case this is not a problem at all.